# How to access data in Class globally in any ViewController in the project

Tags: swift2, swift3

I am a newbie in Swift.

Objective: Access the data globally

How to use Swift to implement a global Temporary storage using below class to store data

In C#,

1) I use a class with static properties

```
 Class TransactionData
    {
        public static DateTime dateTime { get; set; }
        public static int    Qty_Purchase { get; set; }
        public static double  ItemPrice { get; set; }
        public static string  Item_Code { get; set; }

   }
```

2) I can access and set or use the data globally

TransactionData.Item_Code = "P200.XXX";

In Swift,

a) How to implement such class in swift?

To design a class, use CocoaTouch class or Swift Class ?

What is the different between CocoaTouch class ( Where it subclass to UIViewControlelr) and    Swift Class

a) is there a static class in Swift like

```
 public static Class TransactionData
    {
        public static DateTime dateTime { get; set; }
        public static int    Qty_Purchase { get; set; }
        public static double  ItemPrice { get; set; }
        public static string  Item_Code { get; set; }

   }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

If your objective is to access the data globally for temporary storage, just create a struct for your transaction:

```
struct Transaction {
    let date: Date
    let quantity: Int
    let price: Double
    let code: String
}
```

Then just need to create a [singleton](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/cocoa_design_patterns/managing_a_shared_resource_using_a_singleton) and a property to store your transactions:

```
class Shared {
    private init() { }
    static var instance = Shared()
    var transactions: [Transaction] = []
}
```

---

usage:

```
Shared.instance.transactions.append(Transaction(date: Date(), quantity: 2, price: 0.99, code: "item01"))
Shared.instance.transactions.append(Transaction(date: Date(), quantity: 3, price: 2.99, code: "item02"))

Shared.instance.transactions  // [{date "Jan 10, 2017, 2:00 AM", quantity 2, price 0.99, code "item01"},
                              //  {date "Jan 10, 2017, 2:00 AM", quantity 3, price 2.99, code "item02"}]
```

looping through your transactions and editing it:

```
for (index, transaction) in Shared.instance.transactions.enumerated() {
    print(transaction)
    if transaction.code == "item02" {
        Shared.instance.transactions[index] = Transaction(date: transaction.date, quantity: transaction.quantity, price: transaction.price, code: "NEW CODE")
    }
}

Shared.instance.transactions   // [{date "Jan 10, 2017, 2:42 AM", quantity 2, price 0.99, code "item01"}, {date "Jan 10, 2017, 2:42 AM", quantity 3, price 2.99, code "NEW CODE"}]
```

---

If you want to have just a single transaction just add an optional variable to your Shared struct instead of the transactions array:

```
class Shared {
    private init() { }
    static var instance = Shared()
    var transaction: Transaction?
}
```

---

and usage:

```
Shared.instance.transaction = Transaction(date: Date(), quantity: 5, price: 5.0, code: "P200")

print(Shared.instance.transaction?.code ?? "")   // "P200\n"

if let transaction = Shared.instance.transaction {
    Shared.instance.transaction = Transaction(date: transaction.date, quantity: transaction.quantity, price: transaction.price, code: "P300")
    print(Shared.instance.transaction!)   // "Transaction(date: 2017-01-10 05:13:58 +0000, quantity: 5, price: 5.0, code: "P300")\n"

}
```

Comment: How to make it to replace the data and NOT repeating? ie. Item_code store the data at the point it has been changed, ie. If item-Code now is P200, and the next one is P300 when I access it and change it, when I access the item_Code again, I should get P300.

Comment: Just replace the array item with a new one

Comment: is this correct : To Set: Shared.instance.transactions.code ="P300"  To Access:  strcode = Share.instance.transactions.code    Sorry, I am new to Swift syntax and concept.

Comment: You need to pass the array index that you need to change. Get all elements before constructing your transaction object. If editing just get the old item properties that you want to create a new transaction from it.

Comment: If you want to have just a single transaction just add an optional variable to your Shared struct instead of the transactions array `var transaction: Transaction?`

Answer (score -1):

You can follow the step. How to set shared variable in Swift 3

1. Create a model file "TimetableModel.swift"

   ```
   import Foundation
   class TimetableModel {
       static let sharedInstance = TimetableModel()
       let categories:[Day]        
       var user_id = Int()
       // define any variable here
   }
   ```
2. After that create any controller

   ```
   import UIKit
   class TimetableVC: UIViewController {
       override func viewDidLoad() { // now you can access shared variable  
           TimetableModel.sharedInstance.categories[section].name    TimetableModel.sharedInstance.user_id
       }
   }
   ```