# How to save a structure component using NSUserDefaults?

Tags: arrays, swift, swift2, save, nsuserdefaults

I am building a quiz app and wish to enable the user to save a Question and answer combination. In my app I have made a structure to hold the questions and answers.
The user can flick through the many questions and save the ones thy desire.

I wish to save the question and access it in a different viewController. I want to save the question using NSUserDefaults. However when I try and save the current question visible onscreen I am getting an error saying that "Cannot convert value of type 'Question.type' to expected argument type 'AnyObject'". How can I fix this so I can save the question and display it in another view controller?

I am using Swift 2.

```
    struct  Question {
var Question : String!
var Answers : String!

 }

var Questions = [Question]()
var QNumber = Int()

class circulatory: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var labelForQuestion: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var textBoxForAnswer: UITextView!


override func viewDidLoad() {
     //Load Questions
    Questions = [

   Question(Question: "This is Question 1", Answers: "This is answer 1"),

   Question(Question: "This is Question 2", Answers: "This is answer 2"),

   Question(Question: "This is Question 3", Answers: "This is answer 3"),

     ]
     pickQuestion()         

   }

    func pickQuestion() {

    if Questions.count > 0 {
        labelForQuestion.text = Questions[QNumber].Question
        textBoxForAnswer.text = Questions[QNumber].Answer
    }

}


   @IBAction func save(sender: AnyObject) {
    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(Question, forKey: "savedQuestion")
}
```

Comment: you can't. First you will need to make a class instead of a struct. Second you will need to make it NSCoding compliant. Third you will need to use NSKeyedArchiever to convert your object to Data and save the data to disk or to UserDefaults.

Comment: If you don't need to make it persist (writing to disk), you can use a struct. http://stackoverflow.com/a/41560949/2303865

Comment: Could I access  question and answer text  and assign them to a string variable. Then save the string variable?

Comment: Edit your question with your actual code

Comment: You can have any variable type using the shared instance technique

Comment: Btw it is Swift convention to name your variables starting with a lowercase letter. You should update your Xcode to AppStore latest version

Comment: I am going to save the variables question as Questions[QNumber].Question and the answer as Questions[QNumber].Answer. It seems to be working. Thanks for your help anyway man :)

Comment: `struct  Question { var Question : String! var Answers : String!   }` is wrong.

Comment: How is it wrong if it works?

Comment: Should be var question: String

Comment: ah cool no bother il change it there now and see if it still works. Thanks man kind of new to swift so still learning how things are done. :)

Comment: Same applies to the other variables