# How do I make an uploaded image permanent on a view controller in Swift?

Tags: swift, uiimageview, uiimagepickercontroller

I am writing code to allow a user to upload an image on a view controller. The image can be uploaded successfully, but once you navigate away from the view controller and then come back to it, the image they uploaded is gone. How would I make the image a global variable so that when the user returns to the view controller, the image is still present? I am using imagePickerController to select the image for upload. [This is my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MxS5j.png)

Comment: If you just need the to keep the image in memory you can read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41560640/how-to-access-data-in-class-globally-in-any-viewcontroller-in-the-project/41560949?s=1|1.5398#41560949

Comment: BTW don't post screen shots. Post your code.

Comment: Ok thank you! And sorry this is my first time using it. Thanks for the tip.