# Passing data between two *.swift files without prepareForSegue

Tags: swift, delegates

I got two *.swift files. One is the ViewController with the slider.
The second one is a 'drawer' class which draws a line.

The goal is two (1) get a variable from the slider value then (2) pass it to 'drawer' to draw a line and then (3)  inform the slider that it can pass a new value to redraw a line.

Should I use a Delegate to pass data or maybe it is too complicated?
Unfortunately I was unable to find a Delegate methods without `prepareForSeague`.

The code is as follows.

ViewController:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!

    @IBAction func slider(_ sender: UISlider) {
        label.text = String (sender.value)  
    }
```

drawer.swift:

```
import UIKit

// var position =  300  - Here I want to get a variable from the ViewController

class drawer: UIView {

    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
        context?.setLineWidth(2.0)
        let colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB()
        let components: [CGFloat] = [0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0]
        let color = CGColor(colorSpace: colorSpace, components: components)
        context?.setStrokeColor(color!)
        context?.move(to: CGPoint(x: 30, y: 30))
        context?.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: position, y: 400))
        context?.strokePath()
    }
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41560949/2303865

Comment: From where to pass the value in drawer.swift?

Comment: Once the value of slider is changed  it has to be sent to  drawer to redraw the line .

Answer (score 0):

You can declare the variable at the global level.

```
var position = 0.0
class drawer: UIView {}
```

And replace the value here.

```
@IBAction func slider(_ sender: UISlider) {
    label.text = String(sender.value) 
    position = sender.value
}
```

**Suggestion:** For Naming convention: name all your classes starting with an uppercase letter

Comment: Even tho it works you shouldn't declare any variable at global level. Check the link I posted above in comments showing how you can achieve the same results without polluting the global space of your app

Comment: You are right but I didn't see any instance of `drawer.swift` in the code also I am trying to ask him in the comment!

Comment: It is Swift convention to name all your classes starting with an uppercase letter

Comment: Try to understand that is not my class `drawer.swift`

Comment: I know but if you are answering the question you should at least mention it.

Comment: You can leave the comment in the question! also, I am updating my question

Comment: So, as I understand a declaration of variables at global  level is not best practice. Is a shared variable option is the best way? Am I right that a delegation will not be solution here?

Comment: You are absolutely right but you can see you are not making any instance of  `drawer` so the answer will work, also if there is an option for global so it would be used in some case!

Comment: So how can I make an instance of drawer to use a 'Struct' solution?  It looks more sophisticated